# Custom translation of Month names

Tags: translation

How do I customize the translation of the Month name strings in WordPress?

example

"January" be "Jan11" in all of website

Comment: Elaborate your question with code where you want this change.

Comment: Hello Qaisar, 
There is no code ,i need to change the all of string names of months on all of the website

Comment: Is it wordpress site?

Comment: yes it a wordpress site

Comment: The PHP code in Wordpress displays the name of months as specified in the *locale* of the server it runs on. A locale specifies date and time preferences, number formatting and lots more. It is usually associated with a language. If you would like to change e.g. English month names to German, you would change the language of the WP installation to German (in Settings/General). You can't just replace any month name by another. For this to work, the month names would need to go through a .mo/.po translation  using the `__` (double underscore) function.

Comment: Hello jos , i need to just change the string (we can called this translate months names)

Comment: Te right approach is as suggested by @Jos , or you can write a function where you can replace the date string extracted from WordPress functions like `get_the_date()` for  desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your existing `functions.php` file:

```
function ra_change_translate_text( $translated_text ) {
    if ( $translated_text == 'January' ) {
        $translated_text = 'Jan11';
    }
    return $translated_text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'ra_change_translate_text', 20 );
```

If you want to change multiple strings, use this function instead:

```
function ra_change_translate_text_multiple( $translated ) {
    $text = array(
        'January' => 'Jan11',
        'February' => 'Feb22',
        'March' => 'Mar33',
    );
    $translated = str_ireplace(  array_keys($text),  $text,  $translated );
    return $translated;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'ra_change_translate_text_multiple', 20 );
```

You can add as many strings as you want, for example:

```
'April' => 'Apr44',
```

And the new translation can also be in a foreign language. Here's an example with Arabic:

```
'May' => 'مايو',
```

Last notes: If you use this function, keep in mind this will change the string translation ***everywhere*** in your WordPress site: front and back end. **January** will become **Jan11** *everywhere*. Try it and see.

If that is acceptable to you then you're good to go. Otherwise, if you were looking to change the strings only on the front end (for your visitors to see), then consider making the changes to your theme or WordPress website language settings (which can be different from the admin language) - as suggested in some of the comments above.

Also, for reference, I learned about this function here: https://ronangelo.com/change-or-translate-text-on-a-wordpress-theme/. It is a very good post and if you want further information on translating text or themes in WordPress I recommend reading it.

**Update to the original answer:**

This function can only be used with words that are translatable - meaning, those wrapped in these functions `( __(), _e() )`...

However, your comment and the website you linked to have given me a clearer idea of what you are trying to achieve. Simply change the locale of the PHP used to show that date to `ar-LB.UTF-8`. Lebanon is one of the Arabic locales that uses أذار for March, whereas other locales use مارس. The php locale will then render the date as you want it with no need for digging into translations and strings.

So, in your WordPress theme, use this code where you want to display the date instead of the code you are already using:

```
<?php 
   setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar_LB.UTF-8');
   echo strftime("%e %B %Y");
?>
```

In the source code of the page you linked to, the date is displayed within these lines of code:

[image]

Depending on how you organized your theme, that bit could be in `header.php` or maybe even a template part. Find it and you will see that the old PHP code to echo the date will be there between the  tags. Paste the snippet I gave you in its place.

Do keep in mind that if this theme is not your own unique one and you're not using a child theme you might lose that modification if the parent theme is updated.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please try the solution offered there and let us know how it works in case someone else is trying to achieve the same result.

Comment: Many thanks for help , but where i should to paste the code which change the local date 
functions.php of the theme  or server ?

Comment: Paste the whole snippet together wherever you want to display the date in your theme. So, for example, if you are displaying the date in your `header.php` file, paste it there. I will update the answer now with a screenshot to assist you.

Comment: Thanks jsmod for fast replying and ur helps 
This is a plugin (which show the date) and this plugin appears the date based on wordpress this is the message on the plugin  "Todays date (based on your WordPress General Settings)" the plugin called "WP Cloudy"

Comment: Glad to be of assistance. Ok, then this plugin is using the language locale you picked in **Settings > General > Site Language**. WordPress has two Arabic locales, plain *ar* and Moroccan Arabic *ar_MA*. Both use مارس for March. So, you either have to find a Lebanese Arabic translation file for WordPress, OR (the simpler option) disable the plugin and just add that snippet to your theme as described above. I have used that snippet and another to add Hijri date to an Arabic website without problems, it is very convenient and lessens reliance on plugins for simple tasks.

Comment: Glad to help. Friendly word of advice: If you have further questions related to using Arabic with WordPress, I recommend that you always specify that in your questions here on Stack Exchange. As you can see, the solution to your problem ended up being a tiny snippet of code but you could have gotten it a lot faster had your question been explicitly about **how to change the display of Arabic dates in WordPress**. So in the future, just state that up front and describe the issue and what you are trying to achieve so people can answer your actual question and assist you better. :)

Comment: <3 
i will in the future bro 
**
i delete the comment which have the url

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is as suggested by @Jos in a comment to your question , or you can write a function where you can replace the date string extracted from WordPress functions like `get_the_date()` for desired output.

Here is an example function that may help.

```
function my_custom_date($date){
    $new_date = getdate(strtotime($date));

    // Array that holds customized month's name
    $my_months=[
            'January'   => '1st Month',
            'February'  => '2nd Month',
            'March'     => '3rd Month',
            'April'     => '4th Month',
            'May'       => '5th Month',
            'June'      => '6th Month',
            'July'      => '7th Month',
            'August'    => '8th Month',
            'September' => '9th Month',
            'October'   => '10th Month',
            'November'  => '11th Month',
            'December'  => '12th Month',
        ];



        $new_date['month']= $my_months[$new_date['month']];

        return $new_date['month'].' '.$new_date['mday']. ', '. $new_date['year'];

    }
```

Then you can use this function to display dates in your site. For example,

```
echo my_custom_date( get_the_date() ); // Post publish date, within a loop

echo my_custom_date( "May 10, 2017" ); // Outputs: 5th Month 10, 2017
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wp_locale;
echo $wp_locale->get_month('01'); // string between '01' and '12'
```

Doc:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_locale/get_month/